# Storing project-wide global objects in Python

Tags: python

I have a simple game project with structure similar to this:

```
src:
    game.py # <- main module
    projectile.py
    enemy.py
    heroine.py
```

There are several objects that are initialized in the main module `game.py` and I want use them in other modules, like Pygame's sprite groups or a reference to the heroine's sprite for aiming enemy projectiles. I really don't want to pass those references to constructors.

So the question is - **is it ok to create a `common.py` module for storing project-wide globals?** At first I've tried to import `game.py` from other modules, but it seems to create circular dependencies and the game won't start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run across nothing that says this is illegal or poor practice for Python. I used a similar method when I was creating my own game.

A formatting suggestion I have is to use all caps for your variable names, ie.

```
import common

    print common.CONSTANT1
    print common.CONSTANT2
```

or

```
from common import *

    print CONSTANT1
    print CONSTANT2
```

since it will make these variables easy to identify as constants in your code.

Comment: All the project-wide globals are likely not constants.

Comment: Yeah, @martineau is right - they certainly would not be constants.
Anyway, I'm glad to hear that my idea is ok!

Comment: ...and therefore don't need to only have names in all caps. Otherwise there's nothing wrong AFAIK about organizing things this.

Comment: `import *` is not considered a good practice, if name is long use `import common as cmn`, or store a variable that is used a lot in a local variable `const1 = common.CONSTANT1`

Answer (score 1):

You shall organize your code in following way:

```
project_root/
    game/
        __init__.py # "I am package" file, can be empty
        projectile.py
        enemy.py
        heroine.py
```

Put your globals into `__init__.py`, this is common place to hold this sort of stuff.

Your `__init__.py` file might have content like:

```
CODE = "secret"
KEY = "digital"
```

and from your other modules you could get them:

```
from game import CODE, KEY
print CODE
print KEY
```

Note, that there are two options how to import - absolute import (using name of `game` package) and relative one.

Keep it simple and use absolute imports, as PEP 8 recommends.

Comment: Thank you, Jan, your solution looks really neat, but after reading articles about __init__.py it seems more obvious to me to use separate module. Upvoted anyway, thanks!